# SQL Server 2008 free hosting?

Tags: sql-server, hosting

I am not sure if this thing exists but... I know there's free code hosting for svn and svc, where each user can download the code from a central repository and update to it.

Me and a couple of friends are using it, but we are also working against a database. This database is installed only my friend's computer, we are currently struggling with connecting to it. Does any of you know of a free SQL Server hosting plan for development purposes (meaning we won't be exceeding any large size) for us to be able to develop against?

Thank you!
Vondip

**Edit:**

Yes, but I need a computer that can host the server on and be accessible to remote requests around the web. Where do I get that? (I am currently trying to adjust my computer in my local LAN to work that way, it's quite complicated though)

Answer (score 4):

You can download the Express editions for free use.  They have limits on data size (4Gb) and processor usage (1 CPU) but they are otherwise adequate for development.

[SQL 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are some very low-price offers, which are almost free. I think you won't find free hosting for SQL Server.

For example, [Webhost4Life](http://www.webhost4life.com/hosting.asp) has a USD 9.95 offer for an ASP.NET/SQL Server 2GB 5 databases. Seems that you can directly connect to the databas using SQL Management Studio from your machines. Or search on [DiscountASP.net for SQL Server hosting](http://www.discountasp.net/sp_sql-2008-hosting.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think using Express for commercial hosting is against the EULA, and licensing for the 'proper' versions especially Enterprise is a *lot* of money. Thus it won't be free.

Your best bet is really to get your network configured appropriately and use Express.

Comment: You can use sql express for commercial hosting, it used to be the case that you couldn't but they removed this from the EUAL - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/39b04633-0a09-4d8f-b679-33effe154cdc/